# How can I fix the "(0, _reactNativeRedash.withTransition) is not a function" error?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, typeerror, transition

Getting this while creating an animation:

```
const active = new Value(1);
    
  const transition = withTransition(active, { duration: 100 });
  const activeTransition = new Value(0);
```

This function actually exists, but somehow I'm getting this error. How can I fix that? (currently using SDK 39 and react-native-redash 9.1.2)

Comment: How are you declaring this variable? If you are getting this error then clearly it doesn't have the value you expect.

Answer (score 2):

This is because wcandillon completelly refatored this mechanism in early 2020.

Uninstall react native redash and install a compatible version, like v9.3.1 and it will work.